# Writing and Reading from a plist file

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I am currently in need for reading and writing to a plist file.
Here is my current state:
I've created a plist file named "Scores.plist" and I've put it in my Resources folder for my xcode project. Inside the plist file contains a dictionary with the key "Score." The object attached to the key is a NSNumber with a placeholder value of 1010.
When I run my code, I get strange results.
Is my plist located in the wrong place?
I hear that the plist should be located in some documents directory, for reading AND writing. However, I'm not sure where this is, exactly.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

```
-(void)writeToPlistHighScore:(int)scoreNumber {  
    //attempt to write to plist   
    //however both the nslog's in this first section result in "null"
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Scores.plist"];

//NSString *scorePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Scores" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath] retain];
NSLog(@"%@",[plistDict objectForKey:@"Score"]);
[plistDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:scoreNumber] forKey:@"Score"];
[plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
NSLog(@"%@",[plistDict objectForKey:@"Score"]);
[plistDict release];

//Stable code for reading out dictionary data
//this code reads out the dummy variable in Scores.plist located in my resources folder.
// Path to the plist (in the application bundle)
NSString *scorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Scores" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:scorePath] retain];
NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score:%@", [plistData objectForKey:@"Score"]];
NSLog(@"%@",scoreString);

//checking to see where my file is...
//this logs a file path which I don't know means
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory2 = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",@"Scores"]]; 

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]){
    NSLog(@"File don't exists at path %@", path);

    NSString *plistPathBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Scores" ofType:@"plist"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:plistPathBundle toPath: path error:&error]; 
}else{
    NSLog(@"File exists at path:%@", path);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you want to use NSDocumentDirectory instead of NSLibraryDirectory.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

You want to save to your application's documents directory inside its sandbox, not to its application bundle.  You're not allowed to alter anything in your application bundle at runtime.

see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html for a full explanation.

Now the trick is, what if you want to load a default plist file if one hasn't been saved yet?  Well, first check your documents directory, and, if no file has been saved there, then load a template from your resources directory.  Even better, if it's as simple a structure as it seems, just create the NSDictionary in code and then save it using writeToFile:atomically:, which will write in plist format.

There's a nice explanation of plist handling at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5.  It uses a Mac OS X app as its example, but the concepts are transferrable to iOS.

btw, you're taking some unnecessary steps with your retains and releases. dictionaryWithContentsOfFile creates an autoreleased object, so there's no need to retain it, and thus there's no need to release it when you're done.  You can accomplish the same thing you're doing in your first block of code with:

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 
NSLog(@"%@",[plistDict objectForKey:@"Score"]); 
[plistDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:scoreNumber] forKey:@"Score"]; 
[plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES]; 
NSLog(@"%@",[plistDict objectForKey:@"Score"]);
```

plistDict will be autoreleased when the current run loop iterates.  I mention this because you fail to release plistData later in your sample, which is a memory leak if it's not released later on, whereas you could avoid that by just not retaining plistData. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI for a thorough explanation of autoreleased objects.